# Problems to create an index pattern

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elk

I have a problem when I'm trying to create an index pattern in Kibana.

The problem is that when I go to the corresponding section to create an index pattern, I follow the steps indicated by the system, and it seems to be created, but then it always tells me that I have to create one.

I pass screenshots of the process, so you can see what happens.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]